# PL/SQL function to calculate average monthwise for a given date range

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Suppose

```
1st jan count is 20   
2nd jan count is 12   
3rd jan count is 0   
.................   
..................  
31st jan count is 17
```

I need a function which can find the average monthwise .In this case it should be `20+12+17/3` because I dont want to use the day which has count 0

I tried this:-

```
create function(p_date IN Date)
return number is

cursor c_num is
 select  count(distinct attribute8) from mtl_material_transactions  where trunc(transaction_date)=p_date;

l_num number:=0

begin
open c_num;
fetch c_num into l_num;
close c_num;

return sum(l_num);

end;
```

But it is not working as per my requirement.Please help me.I need to find monthwise average for a given date range say *01-April-2013 to 31st Mar-2014.*

**The Test Data is:-**

```
create table kk1 ( ATTRIBUTE8 varchar2(30), TRANSACTION_DATE date );  

insert into kk1 values ( 'LP001', to_date('08.01.2015 15:21:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));   
insert into kk1 values ( 'LP002', to_date('08.01.2015 15:24:33', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));   
insert into kk1 values ( 'LP004', to_date('08.01.2015 15:41:51', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));   
insert into kk1 values ( 'LP005', to_date('08.01.2015 15:43:38', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));   
insert into kk1 values ( 'LP001', to_date('14.01.2015 11:36:13', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));   
insert into kk1 values ( 'LP002', to_date('14.01.2015 11:38:24', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));   
insert into kk1 values ( 'LP001', to_date('14.01.2015 11:40:09', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Comment: Why RDBMS are you using, `Oracle` or `MySQL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is:-

```
FUNCTION Get_attr_avg (p_from_date IN DATE,
                       p_to_date   IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  CURSOR c_attr_avg IS
    SELECT Avg(attr_per_day)
    FROM   (SELECT Count(DISTINCT attribute8) attr_per_day,
                   Trunc(transaction_date)    day
            FROM   mtl_material_transactions
            WHERE  transaction_date BETWEEN p_from_date AND p_to_date
                   AND attribute8 IS NOT NULL
            GROUP  BY Trunc(transaction_date))
    GROUP  BY To_char(day, 'MON-YYYY');
  l_attr_avg NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_attr_avg;
    FETCH c_attr_avg INTO l_attr_avg;
    CLOSE c_attr_avg;

    RETURN l_attr_avg;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
             RETURN 0;
END get_attr_avg;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements. If you want to calculate the average for each month, I'd expect your function to take a date range (and not just single date) and to return more than a single number, namely a number for each month in the date range.

Does the following query calculate what your looking for?

```
SELECT AVG(attribute8) average, TRUNC(transaction_date, 'MONTH') mon
FROM mtl_material_transactions
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Apr-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31-Mar-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
  AND attribute8 <> 0
GROUP BY TRUNC(transaction_date, 'MONTH');
```

Comment: @Codo-No.I am providing the test data.Now I hope you will understand my requirement

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand it. Can you describe what the parameters would be for a given query for that test data and what the result for that query should look like?

Comment: The result should be 4+2/2 i.e sum(count of distinct attribute  per day)/total days.Anyways I got the solution.Thank you.

Comment: @Nikhil In your sample code, you have a function with a single date as input parameter. What's the purpose of that parameter. Can you please make an example that includes the table data, the parameters provided to the function and the expected output. I'm afraid I won't understand it otherwise. And I don't get what you mean by "monthwise".

Comment: @Codo-I have posted the answer.Please have a look at it.It will clarify all your doubt.